# How is the storage trie of a user account which does not belong to any contract?

Tags: contract-design, accounts, state-trie, storage-trie

We know that storage trie (stored in the leaf node of state trie) is storing the contract's data related to an account. Then, what will be stored in the storage trie of a user account which does not belong to any contract? Is it empty in this case?

Comment: Probably the account's nonce and balance, since those two depict that account's state.

Comment: But depending on terminology, one could claim that those two pieces of data are stored inside the State Trie, alongside the Storage Trie (rather than inside the Storage Trie). You might wanna read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/getting-deep-into-ethereum-how-data-is-stored-in-ethereum-e3f669d96033) which covers it pretty well.